# How to wrap a div containing text around another div?

Tags: html, css, text

I am looking for a way to wrap text filled div around another div.

[image]

It seems that I may have missed a vital detail. The text needs to wrap round an embedded YouTube Video. This seems to not work with all the answers you have provided, I have tried all of the given examples and once I embed the video, the text disappears.

Comment: looks like you just want <div class="container"><div class="litle"></div></div> where the css .litle{float:left;}

Answer (score 4):

You can use `float: left`, then `.content` will wrap it if it's next in DOM

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="content">
    The English word world comes from the Old English weorold (-uld), weorld, worold (-uld, -eld), a compound of wer "man" and eld "age," which thus means roughly "Age of Man."[3] The Old English is a reflex of the Common Germanic *wira-alđiz, also reflected in Old Saxon werold, Old High German weralt, Old Frisian warld and Old Norse verǫld (whence the Icelandic veröld).[4]

The corresponding word in Latin is mundus, literally "clean, elegant", itself a loan translation of Greek cosmos "orderly arrangement." While the Germanic word thus reflects a mythological notion of a "domain of Man" (compare Midgard), presumably as opposed to the divine sphere on the one hand and the chthonic sphere of the underworld on the other, the Greco-Latin term expresses a notion of creation as an act of establishing order out of chaos.

'World' distinguishes the entire planet or population from any particular country or region: world affairs pertain not just to one place but to the whole world, and world history is a field of history that examines events from a global (rather than a national or a regional) perspective. Earth, on the other hand, refers to the planet as a physical entity, and distinguishes it from other planets and physical objects.

'World' distinguishes the entire planet or population from any particular country or region: world affairs pertain not just to one place but to the whole world, and world history is a field of history that examines events from a global (rather than a national or a regional) perspective. Earth, on the other hand, refers to the planet as a physical entity, and distinguishes it from other planets and physical objects.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap both divs in a 'container' div and give 'div1' use `float` for the style. This will give you the desired result. See the code below.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1" style="float:left; width: 150px; height: 150px; margin: 10px; background-color: #ff0000;"></div>
  <div class="div2">Wrapping text comes here.</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could place div 1 inside of div 2.

Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Div Test</title>
    <style>
        .outer {
            width:800px;
            height:600px;
            background-color:#22e;
        }

        .inner {
            width:300px;
            height:200px;
            background-color:#e22;
        }
     </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
         <div class="inner">
         </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. `div` inside a `div` with margin and float properties.

https://jsfiddle.net/rnxuLb9u/