# Text goes behind overlapping div

Tags: html, css

I currently have some problems figuring out how to make text content fit the div, with a overlapping div. I currently have this code here:

```css
* {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        html {
          font-family: "Montserrat";
        }
        section {
          min-height: 100vh;
          width: 100%;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          background-color: #1e1f26;
        }
        .container {
          width: 90%;
          max-width: 1000px;
          margin: 50px auto;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        .inner {
          width: 50%;
          height: 600px;
          background-color: #fafafa;
          border-radius: 8px;
        }
        .outer {
          width: 50%;
          min-height: 400px;
          background-color: #303137;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          padding: 30px;
          border-radius: 8px;
          color: white;
          margin-left: -150px;
        }
        .right h1 {
          font-size: 40px;
          font-weight: lighter;
        }
        .right p {
          margin: 20px 0;
          font-weight: 500;
          line-height: 25px;
        }
        .right a {
          text-decoration: none;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          background-color: white;
          color: black;
          padding: 20px 30px;
          display: inline-block;
          letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
```

```html
<section>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="inner">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="outer">
              <div class="content">
                <h1>This is a heading</h1>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

As you can see, the text in the outer div is going under the inner div. I want the text to go towards the outer div, and wrap around it.

I cant just use width, cause the text length will depend on which page im using the blueprint for. This means that the length of the paragraph tag depends on the page. The place of the outer div, will still be at the same spot.

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your desired effects? It's hard to determine your expected output.

Comment: I think this post might be the solution your looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065000/how-to-wrap-a-div-containing-text-around-another-div